# How can you fix sas proc import errors?

Tags: sas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y07Qx.jpg)Here is my simple SAS proc code:

proc import datafile="/home/u63240701/AGIN_BIRTH_RATES/TEST-AGIN/AHRI_STPTIME.csv"
out=sv   dbms=csv replace;
run;

Below is the error message from the log panel

I have not seen similar error. This is the first time. The code ran smooth  yesterday, but today it's not working

Comment: This does not look like a Proc Import related error. My best guess is that it is a setup error of some sort. Restart your system and try again.

Answer (score 1):

That arises from unbalanced code submitted in SAS Studio (e.g. parentheses, quotes, etc.).

You can either restart your session, or use the balancing code below - submitting it until you get "ERROR: No matching %MACRO statement for this %MEND statement." in the log. It often resolves the issue, occasionally it won't...

```
*'; *"; *); */; %mend; run;
```

It's a good idea to add the above as a Snippet in Studio.